# QSslCertificate crashes when i try to load a cer file

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, certificate

i have this code in Qt

```
QFile file(address);
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
const QByteArray bytes = file.readAll();

qDebug()<<"Length : " + QString::number(bytes.length());

const QSslCertificate cert(bytes,QSsl::Der);
```

when i try this code in windows 7 64bit it works perfectly but when i compile it for linux it crashes every time when it hits the last line even it gave me the right Lenght but it crashes with these lines in terminal.

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_KEY_free
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

whats going on here i didn't use any QSslSocket in my code, i'm stuck in this problem for days now.
qt version 5.4.2 tested on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit and CentOS 6.4 64bit

**UPDATE**
i used openssl-1.0.2d for Windows and Linux both.

Comment: did you figured out this issue? i have the same annoying issue

Comment: @mihaipop sadly no. i'm sort of leaving this issue behind but I'll be glad if someone solve it. although i suspect maybe there is a conflict in openssl and qt. what is your version of qt and openssl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this, what I did was:

OpenSSL 1.1.0 is not compatible with QT so i cloned the 1.0.1 stable version:
Here is the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52905

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl -b OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable
```

then install it in custom location:

```
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-stable
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Get the QT Sources, then when you want to built them you have to link the installed OpenSSL:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -openssl-linked
```

see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html

This is my configuration:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/opt/openssl-stable/lib -lssl -lcrypto' ./configure -prefix /opt/qt5.7_linux_staticssl -opensource -confirm-license -release -openssl-linked -I /opt/openssl-stable/include/openssl -L /opt/openssl-stable/lib
```

and if the qt build gives you an error that it doesn't find some ssl struct, just copy the /opt/openssl-stable/include/openssl headers to /usr/include/openssl or wherever qt is looking for them(you can see that when qt build fails)

And that's it

Comment: Great man! Thought some conflict between openssl and qt cause it. Tnx